# Install SSL in Lightsail / bitnami - NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have got the SSL error after installing the SSL in the Lightsail environment.

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: example.com
Issuer: example.com
```

I have put below lines to /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf

```
SSLCertificateChainFile <path>
SSLCertificateFile <path>
SSLCertificateKeyFile <path>
```

And restart the Apache:

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

The SSL cert does not seems work.

I don't know where example.com come from!!!!

I am struggling with it now. What did I do wrongly??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WTX~ The problem is solved.

It's because it's bundled with Wordpress.
What I need to edit is the "Wordpress version" configure file:

/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/wordpress-https-vhost.conf

Answer (score 0):

I installed SSL by assigning a static IP address to lightsail and entering that into the DNS. Then booting lightsail with IP attached then running
[image]